# How to sed to select two fields

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

I have a log like the following:

```
[T:OK:OK:SV[server1-ph:12345]:PHP-APACHE:*] LastAccesssDate : 10-30-2019
[T:OK:OK:SV[server2-ph:12346]:PHP-APACHE:*] LastAccesssDate : 04-10-2020
```

What I want to do is get the server and the `LastAccesssDate` like the following output:

```
server1 10-30-2019
server2 04-10-2020
```

I'm trying with this sed command, but it doesn't work.

```sh
echo "[T:OK:OK:SV[server2-ph:12346]:PHP-APACHE:*] LastAccesssDate : 04-10-2020" \
    | sed -r 's/SV\[([^-]*);^LastAccesssDate : ([^*]*).*/\1 \2/g'
```

Comment: you have to look at the list of characters that need a backslash... I have a hard time remembering them

Comment: Also I think you are missing a * before the ;

A common mistake in regexes is thinking that a character class repeats... it does not... it needs a *

Comment: `awk -F'[]:[]+' '{sub(/-[[:alpha:]]+/,"");print $6, $NF}' log.txt`  the I'm not so sure answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `sed` wasn't **quite** right.

```
echo "[T:OK:OK:SV[server2-ph:12346]:PHP-APACHE:] LastAccesssDate : 04-10-2020" | sed -r 's/.*SV\[([^:]+).*LastAccesssDate : (.*)/\1 \2/g'
server2-ph 04-10-2020
```

Answer (score 2):

With sed, I've found that removing the stuff you don't want is easier than capturing the stuff you want to capture.

Using that strategy , try this sed command:

```
sed -e 's/^[[].*[[]//' -e 's/-.*LastAccesssDate ://'
```

The first edit `-e 's/^[[].*[[]//'`removes everything to the second open square bracket `[`.   It's important to note that since `[` is recognized as a special character, you need to escape it as:  `[[]`.

The second edit `-e 's/-.*LastAccesssDate ://'` removes every thing from the next dash `-` the colon `:` following 'LastAccessDate'.  This leaves us with the server and the date.

Answer (score 0):

With awk, you could get:

```
$ awk -F'[\[- ]' '{print $3, $(NF-2)"-"$(NF-1)"-"$NF}' filename
server1 10-30-2019
server2 04-10-2020
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/^\[[^[]*\[\([^-]*\).*\s/\1 /' file
```

Remove everything from the starting `[` to the next `[` and then everything from the next `-` to the last space.